# Equivalent to the deprecated <sec:authorize> ifNotGranted attribute

Tags: jsp, spring-security, jsp-tags

I would like to prevent an image having a link if a user does NOT have a certain role.  e.g.

```
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ACCOUNTS" ><img src="someimage.jpg"/></sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ACCOUNTS" ><a href="somelink.htm"><img src="someimage.jpg"/></a></sec:authorize>
```

However ifNotGranted and ifAllGranted are now deprecated in favour of the access expression.  I can see that ifAllGranted can be replicated with:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ACCOUNTS')"><a href="somelink.htm"><img src="someimage.jpg"/></a></sec:authorize>
```

But how can ifNotGranted be replicated using the access method?  Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: access="isFullyAuthenticated() and not hasRole('ROLE_ACCOUNTS')"

Comment: @Ritesh Thanks the `isFullyAuthenticated()` could be very usefull for another page.  Here however page access is only available to logged in users.  `not hasRole('ROLE_ACCOUNTS')` did the trick.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

SpEL expression can be negated with `!` operator:

```
<sec:authorize access="!hasRole('ROLE_ACCOUNTS')">...</sec:authorize>
```

**See also:**

- [6. Spring Language (SpEL)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Answer (score 7):

In case if you have many files to update, I recommend use the regular express to search and replace

find

```
<sec:authorize\s+ifAnyGranted="([^"]+)"
```

replace with

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('$1')"
```

and search

```
<sec:authorize\s+ifNotGranted="([^"]+)"
```

replace with

```
<sec:authorize access="!hasAnyRole('$1')"
```

Hope this can save you time