# Recognization of logged user in Spring 3 project JSP

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have project secured via Spring security. I need to determine whether the user, who just accessed to JSP is already logged in. I've read some articles, posts here and documentation and tried to implement it with this code:

```jsp
<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
            USER NOT LOGGED IN
    <td><a href="<c:url value="/login"/>">Login</a></td>
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">       
            USER LOGGED IN
    <td><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout</a></td>
</sec:authorize>
```

Nevertheless I always get "USER LOGGED IN" and I can't realize why.. This is my security context

```xml
<beans xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/login*" security="none" auto-config="true"/>
<security:http pattern="/denied" security="none"/>

<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied" servlet-api-provision="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/edit/**" access="ROLE_EDIT"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"  authentication-failure-url="/denied"
                         default-target-url="/"/>
    <security:logout  logout-success-url="/login" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="adam" password="adampassword" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            <security:user name="jane" password="janepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <security:user name="sue" password="suepassword" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDIT"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: What happens if you check for ROLE_USER instead of ROLE_ANONYMOUS ?

Comment: still the same :-/ I get only USER LOGGED IN message :-S it's quite confusing...

Answer (score 2):

If a page is accesible to anyone, as set in your secruity context, you can conditionally display content like so :

```
<sec:authorize var="loggedIn" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

and using fairly standard jstl you can then :

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${loggedIn}">
    <td><a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Logout</a></td>
```

A tad of googling tells me [ifnotgranted is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953194/equivalent-to-the-deprecated-secauthorize-ifnotgranted-attribute)

Comment: Nevertheless this isn't working as well :-/ I've already tried this before, so there might be problem somewhere else

Comment: @Dworza what error do you get, what does the log say ? You need to enbale security tags

Comment: I've got them enabled...in fact it does no error... it's seems to be working properly. Nevertheless it always seems, that user is logged in even though he isn't